# UnsupportedOperationExeception when writing in Cassandra table

Tags: scala, cassandra, phantom-dsl

I have the following class :

```
case class AucLog(timestamp:  UUID, modelname: String, good: Int,
              list: List[Double])

class AucDatabase(override val connector : CassandraConnection)
extends Database[AucDatabase](connector) {
object users extends CMetrics with Connector
}
object AucDatabase extends AucDatabase(AucConnector.connector)

abstract class AucMetrics extends Table[AucMetrics, AucLog] {
 object id extends UUIDColumn with PartitionKey
 object name extends StringColumn
 object ud extends IntColumn
 object zob extends ListColumn[Double]
}

abstract class CMetrics extends AucMetrics with RootConnector {  
def store(metric : AucLog): Future[ResultSet] = {
insert.value(_.id, metric.timestamp)
  .value(_.name, metric.modelname)
  .value(_.ud, metric.good)
  .value(_.zob, metric.list)
  .consistencyLevel_=(ConsistencyLevel.ONE)
  .future()
```

}

```
DmpDatabase.create()
AucDatabase.create()

val pd = DmpDatabase.users.myselect()

val timeout = new Timeout(500000)
val result = Await.result(pd, timeout.duration)

"<--- this attempt to read from my database is working - no problemo   ---> "
val todf = result.records.map { elem => elem.idcat }
val rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(todf)

import spark.implicits._
rdd.toDF().show(100)

---> I'm storing one line in my database to be sure that it is not empty when 
   i'm reading it. 
AucDatabase.users.store(new AucLog(UUIDs.timeBased(), "tyron", 0, List(0.1)))
val second = AucDatabase.users.myselect()
val resultmetric = Await.result(second, timeout.duration)

 -----> this line cause the Execption
val r = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(resultmetric.records).toDF().show(
```

What I do not understand is that i'm doing basically the same thing with both databases. Yet, one is throwing the following error : UnsupportedOperationException : No encoder found for com.outworkers.phantom.dsl.UUID.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

First of all the `store` method is macro generated so you don't need to create one. The problem you are having is likely not related to phantom at all, but to some kind of Spark construct.

The phantom `UUID` is nothing more than a type alias for `java.util.UUID`, so I'm quite surprised there is no straight up encoder for a default type. If you help me out with the full name of the `Encoder` class, including the package, I can figure out explicitly what is broken.

Comment: I found my mistake and did'nt update the status of this post. The mistake was that I tried to cast a vector into a list in the store function. Performing the cast at this moment was generating this mistake. Thank you for trying to help me :)